# Restoring deleted users OneDrive file

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business

Situation is like, user deleted from the system and his shared OneDrive file also deleted. How can I get back deleted file?

Answer (score 1):

user needs to go to the website version:

https://onedrive.live.com/

once loaded on the left hand side menu at the bottom click on "Recycle Bin" -> select item and restore:

[image]

**EDIT**

4 months ago is pushing it. Depends on when the user was deleted? by the sounds of it it was provisioned a month ago which goes inline with the files missing as it takes 30 day to provision. Files might still exist.

to restore the user. Go to central admin -> under users on the left hand side select "deleted users" -> select the given user and hit restore:

go to https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home?rc=1

then

[image]

then

[image]

finally assign password to user.

now login to one drive:

https://onedrive.live.com/

find the file and restore -> save file in SharePoint or 365 group.

Comment: User left  4 month before and shared file was in another user's OneDrive seen last time one month before. Now user suddenly saw that file disappeared. I tried above mentioned things, there no Files on the Recycle Bin. I tried to get deleted user by the PowerShell but no chances. I think 90 days left, but I can see still deleted user name on the system by the PowerShell. But I can't access his OneDrive. Do you know how can I access to deleted user ONeDrive?

Comment: ahh might be a little late though but you could try. Do you have central admin access on 365?

Comment: Yes I have. How can I try?I tried with PowerShell nothing changed.I can access to another user OneDrive from PowerShell but only not for that deleted user

Comment: Dear Ali, I checked it already. User not existing on deleted users list.What else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You can recover/restore files from user's OneDrive recycle bin.  Deleted files are stored in the bin for 93 days.

More information is available [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Restore-deleted-files-or-folders-in-OneDrive-949ada80-0026-4db3-a953-c99083e6a84f?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE)